# Why cast in a Stream<E>?

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-stream

I put some numbers into a `HashSet`, then try to get an `int[]` using stream:

```
    HashSet set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    set.add(1);
    set.add(2);
    set.add(3);

    int[] ii = set.stream().mapToInt(i -> ((Integer)i).intValue()).toArray();
```

It works fine. My question is **why I need to cast `i` into an `Integer` for it to work?** If I don't cast, `i` stays an `Object`.

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--), `stream()` should return a `Stream<E>`, where `E` in this case is `Integer`. That is why I did not anticipate the cast.

Comment: Look at the declared type of `set` - you're using the raw type. Was that intentional? If you used a `HashSet<Integer>` as the declared type you may well find things work better.

Comment: My bad. A careless overlook. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the claim of duplication, if you know the answer, then it is a duplicate. But if you *don't* know the answer (and confused like I was), then it is actually a very different starting point. Imagine someone encountering the exact same problem as mine, who has no idea where it went wrong and does not suspect anything related to "raw type", would he have searched and found the other question? A definite NO.

Comment: The first thing that should have given you a hint was the warning your compiler probably gave you. Warnings are your friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have HashSet as RawType, thats why this problem is coming.
Try to make this:

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
set.add(1);
set.add(2);
set.add(3);
int[] ii = set.stream().mapToInt(i -> (i).intValue()).toArray();
```